# How can I define a javascript object in typoscript

Tags: javascript, typo3, typoscript

I want to create a javascript object dynamically in typoscript and fill it with typoscript constants. I did it like this and it works because I dont use braces in my js part. (only for the constants)

```
page {
    jsInline {
        10 = TEXT
        10.stdWrap.dataWrap (
            var  data = new Object;
            data['name'] = '{$plugin.tx_example.settings.config.name}';
            data['value'] = '{$plugin.tx_example.settings.config.value}';
        )
    }
}
```

But I want to write JS Objects with braces. 
Is there a way to use a javascript object like everybody is used to do it? or is there a better solution for it?

```
page {
    jsInline {
        10 = TEXT
        10.stdWrap.dataWrap (
           var data = {
              name: '{$plugin.tx_example.settings.config.name}',
              value: '{$plugin.tx_example.settings.config.value}'
           } 
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: what are you trying to say. kindly explain more your problem and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @SyedKashanAli I know what he wants. `page.jsInline` is a cObject and and thus, the curly braces have a special meaning.

Comment: @DannyStey I don't know the answer right now and have no chance of testing, but did you try a backslash before the curly braces?

Comment: Backslash can only be used to escape dots in TypoScript variable names. It doesn't work with curly braces. However, when using value or wrap it works fine. In your examples there is no need to use a dataWrap.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be careful about the braces. if these braces occur as first character in a line TYPO3 tries to interpret that as typoscript.

Avoid braces at the beginning of lines.

---

Hint:
comments could be problematic also. especially multi-line comments (`/* ... */`) as TYPO3 closes this kind of comment (TYPO3 starts it with a `/*`at the line beginning) only on a line starting with `*/`

---

In your example the solution would be to move the closing brace of the javascript 'data' at the end of the 'value:' line

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
page {
    jsInline {
        10 = TEXT
        10.value (
           var data = {
              name: '{$plugin.tx_example.settings.config.name}',
              value: '{$plugin.tx_example.settings.config.value}'
           } 
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: the usage of `.value` instead of `.stdWrap.dataWrap` is possible as only typoscript constants are used. otherwise it does not change anything about the possible misinterpretation of braces.